# What does 'op' mean in python's fcntl.ioctl?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, fcntl

According to the [fcntl documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html) the usage of `fcntl.ioctl` is as follows:

```
 fcntl.ioctl(fd, op[, arg[, mutate_flag]])
```

with `op` defined as

```
The operation is defined by op and is operating system dependent. These codes are also found in the fcntl module.
```

It does not answer 'what' op is. Is it an int? A string? A structure? How to be able to use this command properly e.g. on a Linux platform?

Comment: It says that the `op` parameter is limited to values that can fit in 32 bits which (to me) implies that it is an `int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with many of the other functions in the fcntl and os modules, `ioctl` is a thin wrapper around the OS system call of the same name. If you consult [the manpage for that system call](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) you will see that it's an integer.

The additional argument (after `op`) to `ioctl` could be just about anything. `ioctl` has notoriously variable arguments that depend on exactly what the request is and even what piece of kernel or driver code receives and processes the request. Difference drivers can even reuse the integer values of `op` to mean different things (although they're encouraged to coordinate to avoid this kind of duplication).